# MemoryStream outOfMemory exception on serialize c#

Tags: c#, memorystream, datacontractserializer

I have this code in my program

```
public static T CloneObjectGraph<T>(this T obj) where T : class 
{
    var serializer = new DataContractSerializer(typeof(T), null, int.MaxValue, false, true, null);
    using (var ms = new System.IO.MemoryStream())
    {
         serializer.WriteObject(ms, obj);
         ms.Position = 0;
         return (T)serializer.ReadObject(ms);
    }
}
```

Whenever I run it it throws an exception outOfMemoryException
Is there a better way to use memorystream or can I change this code with filestream or maybe increase the memory?

EDIT:
as @Yuriy Faktorovich suggested I tried the Clone method

```
public static T Clone<T>(this T obj)
{
    if (!typeof(T).IsSerializable)
    {
        throw new ArgumentException("The type must be serializable", "obj");
    }

    if (Object.ReferenceEquals(obj,null))
    {
        return default(T);
    }

    IFormatter formatter = new BinaryFormatter();
    Stream ms = new MemoryStream();
    using (ms)
    {
        formatter.Serialize(ms, obj);
        ms.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
        return (T)formatter.Deserialize(ms);
    }

}
```

but it gives me an excpetion that the "type in assembly not marked as serializable"
I am using SqlMetal to create the classes from database

Comment: How about instead of using streams to clone objects, making them `ICloneable` instead?

Comment: Maybe you have a circular reference? Many serializers have a setting for max depth. You should verify this is not your issue.

Comment: Thanks for your replies Yuriy Faktorovich and N-ate. Can you give me an example on how to change my code with IClonable or check the max depth?

Comment: The ICloneable suggestion was @YuriyFaktorovich

Comment: Instead of having this method, make the usages of T have an ICloneable constraint on it, then just call their Clone method. You'll probably want to take care with the shallow vs deep implementation and watch out for circular references.

Comment: Can you give me an example. I think it's a good approach to my problem. @yuriy faktorovich

Comment: Perhaps cloning the object graph, in and of itself, isn't the right solution to the *problem* that caused you to start down this route. Perhaps revisit what drove the need to clone objects in the first place, and see if something else can be done instead?

Comment: Can I somehow change my code to use FileStream instead of MemoryStream. Is that a good solution?